# For an array with object items how does one lift / level up the properties of each item's sub-structure to the item's root level?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, mapping

I have an array with objects where each item has the following structure ...

```
[{
  user: { /* ... more (nested) user data ... */ },
  vacation: {
    id: 'idValue',
    name: 'nameValue',
    startDate: 'dateValue',
  },
},...]
```

I want to transform each object item into the following structure ...

```
{
  user: { /* ... more (nested) user data ... */ },
  id: 'idValue',
  name: 'nameValue',
  startDate: 'dateValue',
}
```

... thus, the properties of the `vacation` sub-data have to become properties at the parent structure's (root) level.

How could one achieve such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const restult = yourArray.map(({user,vacation:{id,name,startDate}})=>({user,id,name,startDate}));
```

Comment: You can avoid having to destructure every property of vacation, and just spread the whole object into the result. `yourArray.map(({ user, vacation }) => ({ user, ...vacation }));`

Comment: @pilchard I am using TypeScript, and it tells me "'user' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.", is there a way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: is their a `user` property inside the `vacation` object? if so it will overwrite your top-level `user` property